# Как системно свернуть ExpandableListView (или проблема при отображении ExpandableListView)

Tags: expandablelistview, android-studio, android

Попробую подробно изложить свою проблему:
У меня в программе используется кастомный ExpandableListView.
group элементы заполняются через `ArrayList<Map<String, String>>`, информация для которого берётся из SQL базы данных (назовём её ОСНОВНОЙ БД, и, предположим, у нас N group-элементов).

child элементы заполняются через `ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>>`, информация для которых берётся из N различных других баз данных (назовём их ДОЧЕРНИЕ БД).

На каждом groupView у меня имеется кнопка DELETE, при нажатии на которую удаляется строка информации  об этом group элементе из ОСНОВНОЙ БД, удаляется соответсвующая ДОЧЕРНЯЯ БД и заново обновляется ExpandableListView (т.е. отчищаются массивы, заново заполняются из БД, заново создаётся адаптер и присваивается ExpandableListView).

Всё работает хорошо, кроме одного момемта:
Если у меня

1. group элемент всего один.
2. Его второуровневый список развёрнут.
3. И в этой ситуации я нажимаю DELETE
       программа выдаёт ошибку.

> logcat:
>
> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:
> Invalid index 0, size is 0
>             at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
>             at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
>             at ru.uskov.dmitry.colors.MyExpListAdapter.getChildView(MyExpListAdapter.java:99)
>     .....

Видно, что ошибка возникает при отображении списка.
При этом, после того, как программа выдаст ошибку и завершиться, я опять запущу активити с этим listView, всё работает хорошо (т.е., как и ожидается, ничего не отобразиться (мы ведь уже удалили последний элемент, помните?)).

Стоит отметить, что если:

1. group-элементов>1, то всё работает хорошо;
2. group-элемент 1, но он свёрнут, то тоже всё работает хорошо.

В чём может быть проблема? Или как можно системно свернуть второуровневый список? (Знаю, плохое решение проблемы, но хоть какое-то.)

P.S. Код не скинул, т.к. его довольно много и в нескольких файлах.

Comment: проблема в getGroupCount() методе вашего адаптера. Он сообщает, что кол-во групп = 1, при том, что их реально 0

Comment: А свернуть группу можно так:

    collapseGroup(int position);